# Cannot boot Alpine Linux due to crashed Nginx process

Tags: process, nginx, alpine-linux

I have installed Alpine Linux ISO on a VM on my machine and have spent a while getting everything set up for an IOT communications server. I'm quite liking the lightweight environment that it provides, but I have run into an issue that's prohibiting me from booting up.

I initially made Nginx start on boot with `rc-update add nginx default` and then edited the Nginx config file. Because Nginx wouldn't start, I did a `^C` to get out of it (Nginx seemed to be hanging) and changed the config again in an attempt to fix the problem. However, this time it said that the process was already running (even after I stopped it) so I decided to reboot.

However, because I made it start on boot, and presumably because my config is still wrong, I can't even boot Alpine up!

It just hangs at:

```
* /run/nginx: correcting owner
* Starting nginx ...
```

I therefore have the following two questions:

1. **Is there a way to force it to continue booting even if Nginx could not be started?**
2. **Is there a way I can boot my VM in its current state, or will I have to build it from scratch again?**

I find it a little concerning that it's so easy to cause it to not even boot up, given that this is going to be used for critical IOT infrastructure.

Nginx config was derived from [here](https://dev.to/jackmiras/laravel-with-php7-4-in-an-alpine-container-3jk6) (note though that I'm *not* using Docker).

Comment: How did you "already stopped it"? (`kill` or `systemctl` or `service`?) I haven't played with arch for a while, but the install should be easily recoverable booting from a live environment and reverting your config errors to the backups you made before changing things. I would actually expect it to continue booting if almost any process failed or exited non-zero, how long did you wait? On a philosophical note "IOT" is not "critical"...so maybe chill a bit, also know that the system works >99.99% and it's -your- error that should be "a little concerning"

Comment: Yeah it didn’t take too long to reinstall so I did so. Nevertheless, I’ll remember next time to do proper backups before I make changes. For "sys" disk mode installs, is it possible to perform a local backup/restore with `lbu`? If so, can this be done using SFTP rather than a USB drive?

Comment: Since I've never heard of lbu and a quick search reveals nothing, maybe, maybe-not. What is lbu? All linux binaries can have their output piped over a network.

Comment: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_local_backup

Comment: Why not just snapshot the VM?

Comment: Won't always be on a VM... Many of our systems aren't.

Comment: Right, well. Maybe time to ask at arch/lbu boards. (Cheers for link btw - always something new to learn) I'd still think some kind of deployable default image would be the thing, either for installs or PXE.